# How can I convert horizontal touch scroll action to vertical?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

There are some topics discussing this but none of them could fit my needs.

I have created a page for horizontal scrolling. It works fine. When the user scrolls down, the content scrolls horizontal. Just two elements, one is turned to the side, the other one turns back the content. fine.

But now the problem is, if the user is clever and thinks "oh its horizontal content, so i have to scroll horizontally" (on notebook pad). It doesnt work, it does nothing. The user doesn't know that its a div turned sideways.

So, Is there a Javascript possibility to tell my div "If users (try to) scroll horizontal, just scroll vertical."

Thanks

Comment: I'm frustrated with your UI just reading about it. Maybe a person has to see it to love it. :P

Comment: @isherwood thats what I call constructive criticism, thanks for your help in solving my problem.